# Visual studio 2013 ultimate Intellitrace issue

Tags: visual-studio-2013, intellitrace

I have Visual studio 2012 Professional already installed on my machine. I installed Visual studio Ultimate. I am not seeing Intellitrace windows or in IntelliTrace options in Tools-->Options in VS 2013.

I know, IntelliTrace is not available with Professional version. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Sounds like a side by side issue. Am I reading it right that the VS Professional you installed is 2012 but the VS Ultimate you install is 2013, and the 2013 Ultimate version still don't have IntelliTrace? Can you have a quick check that IntelliTrace binaries exist under "%ProgramFiles%\Visual Studio 2013\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\IntelliTrace"?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here should be supported. There are a couple of things that you can do to trouble shoot the issue.

1) Double check that you are actually launching Visual Studio 2013. I know that this sounds silly, but different versions of Windows will set up file or project associations differently. So, though you have installed 2013, it is possible that your regular workflow is actually still launching 2012. Check the splash screen and/or the Help > About dialog.

2) Reset Visual Studio. It is possible that something got corrupted in your extensions cache during your installation that is preventing Visual Studio from recognizing IntelliTrace. This should be relatively simple:

- Launch the "Developer Command Prompt For Visual Studio 2013"
- cd to [Program files x86]\Microsoft Visual Studio 2013
- Execute the command "devenv /updateconfiguration" followed by "devenv /setup"

The last step may take a number of minutes depending on your system configuration. After it is finished, relaunch Visual Studio to see if IntelliTrace is available.